# How do I use an external javascript class in html?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, class, webpack

Import the main.js file built with Web-pack into html script tag
I want to use the main.js class, but I can't.

Here is my local setting first.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var path = require("path");
var glob = require("glob");
var constants_1 = require("ts-loader/dist/constants");
var entries = glob.sync("./src/modules/*.ts");

var rules = [
    {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: "ts-loader"
    }
];

var module = {
    rules: rules
};
// webpack configuration
var config = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: module,
    mode: 'development',
    cache: true,
};
exports["default"] = config;
```

**tsConfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true
  },
  "files": [
here is my  typescript file paths.
  ]
}
```

It's my typescript code before web pack build.

```js
export class Myclass1 {
//Class contents
}
```

```js
export class Myclass2 {
//Class contents
}
```

```js
export class Myclass3 {
//Class contents 
//I want use this class.
}
```

Then, HTML code  here.

main.js and html file are in the same folder.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"> </script>
<script> 
 var test = new Myclass3();
</script>
</body>
```

program run in the chrome I got  **Uncaught ReferenceError: Myclass3 is not defined.**

Why defined module?

I tried  Myclass3 export , but I can't fixed.

please help.